# Create a Total row in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to create a new row in my dataframe that adds up the sums for only column A B and C and have the means for column D and E. I have tried doing something like:

```
df.loc['totals'] = df['daily budget', 'weekly budget', 'monthly budget'].sum() + df['average spent monthly','average spent yearly'].mean()
```

It didnt work. Should I try to define each value by doing something like

```
sum1 = df['daily budget'].sum()
sum2 = df['weekly budget'].sum()
sum3 = ....
mean1 =df['average monthly'].mean()
mean2 = ....
```

And fill in the cell?

Comment: You should give a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without data, it is hard to understand what do you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with your approach then this should work.

```
sum1 = df['daily budget'] + df['weekly budget'] + df['monthly budget']

mean1 = (df['average spent monthly'] + df['average spent yearly'])/2

df['total'] = sum1 + mean1
```

Comment: I get a nan result for all columns using this method.

Comment: check your data types with df.dtypes to verify that those columns are numeric data types

Comment: They are all float64 except for one which is an object because its a bunch of names. On the bottom of the list it says dtype:Object though. I though i resolved this problem when I used pd.to_numeric on columns containing numbers.

Comment: Is it possible to add a snippet of the dataframe so we can see?